# Random variable when sample space is a singleton set. (Deterministic experiment)

Tags: probability-theory, terminology, definition

This is about how random variables are defined. In some texts, I see that a **random** variable is associated with the sample space of **random** experiments, that is experiments with more than one possible outcome while in other texts, I see that a random variable is simply a real valued function of sample space (the experiment could be random or deterministic).

I'm confused– If the experiment is deterministic, that is, the experiment has only one possible outcome. Would it be correct to call it a random variable on such a sample space which is a singleton set?

Does the definition of random variable require you to consider sample space of random experiments (aka non-deterministic experiments) only?

Comment: There's no reason not to have a random variable with known value, it's just a sort of degenerate case.

Comment: @lulu Oh I don't know, I was wondering if maybe we can call it a deterministic variable instead of random variable? Because then why call it a **random** variable if you can use it for random and non-random experiment, you know what I'm saying?

Comment: If you had a variable with unknown distribution, it would be very cumbersome to carve out exceptions for degenerate cases.  Best to keep one term for all the cases.

Comment: @lulu yeah that makes sense honestly but then why the word **random** in **random** experiments?

Comment: I don't understand.  If you know in advance that some trial is going to yield a fixed outcome all the time, then it would be odd to phrase that probabilistically.  Why bring in all that machinery if it serves no purpose?  But "experiments" often have uncertain outcome.  Rolling a die is an experiment .  Even measuring a signal is an uncertain experiment as noise, if nothing else, makes it impossible to predict the outcome with certainty.

Comment: Oh, no. This is only a matter of definition. I understand what you're saying, for practical purposes is correct. But just for sake of being pedantic with the terminologies... Someone asked me this question and I've been wondering about it since, so I asked.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same sort of thing as counting a square as a special case of a rectangle. In mathematics we've learned over time that it's not worth excluding special cases from our definitions; "random" includes the special case of determinism, which is just when a specific outcome happens with probability $1$.

There are many reasons we've learned to do this; a simple one in this context is that we want to perform operations on random variables, such as adding them or applying functions to them, and it can happen that operations performed on "actually random" random variables can produce deterministic ones (for example taking certain limits). So we include all of them so we can talk about all of them uniformly.